# MapboxGL display user location, bad acuracy

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, mapbox

I'm working on an (PWA) app where the user is meant to navigate through the map and collect rewards by visiting a store's coordinates on the map. I'm currently using a [React wrapper](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) for Mapbox which has been great so far but the user location's accuracy has not been great so I was wondering if someone has found a workaround for displaying the user's exact location in the map.

This is how I'm displaying the user's location.

```
    <div className="flex flex-auto h-screen overflow-hidden">
      <ReactMapGL
        {...viewport}
        height="100%"
        width="100%"
        onViewportChange={(nextViewport: any) => setViewport(nextViewport)}
        mapboxApiAccessToken="foo"
        onResize={clearPopupInformation}
        onWheel={clearPopupInformation}
        onClick={clearPopupInformation}
      >
        <GeolocateControl
          style={geolocateControlStyle}
          positionOptions={{ enableHighAccuracy: true }}
          trackUserLocation={true}
          auto
          showUserLocation={true}
        />
        {
            // ...other stuff
        }
      </ReactMapGL>
    </div>
```

I've found the following:

- https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/1036#issuecomment-652642430
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation#DetectingUserLocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issue only occurs on web browsers where your location in calculated using your IP address, when using a mobile device the built-in GPS is used to calculate your exact location.

You will need HTTPs to ask mobile users for their location, there are many ways to use HTTPs in react but I combined these two:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/
- https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Useful guide here: https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert